# How to filter out a hemisphere of Allen Brain Atlas data with the BSB?

Tags: allen-sdk, bsb-framework

I would like to reconstruct a single (i.e., left) hemisphere, so that it takes less resources to be plotted and less time to compile and eventually simulate. I have configured an `AllenStructureLoader` and I use it in my `PlacemenStrategy`. Can I tell the `PlacementStrategy` to place cells in only 1 of the 2 hemispheres? Would such filter be used in the connectivity as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `AllenStructureLoader` loads entire Allen structures and no filtering is available if they belong to structures with the same ID.

For now your best bet would be to subclass the `AllenStructureLoader` and to override its `get_voxelset` method. I'm not sure if the Allen Brain Atlas provides hemisphere metadata to do such a filter, but the brain is rather symmetrical, so you may just get away with filtering out the half-width of the total region:

```
class HemisphereLoader(AllenStructureLoader):
  def get_voxelset(self):
    vs = super().get_voxelset()
    # Take out the voxels of `vs` that you're interested in
    return vs
```

Alternatively you could use the `AllenStructureLoader`, or the Allen SDK in a script to load both hemispheres, export it to NRRD, filter the NRRD using your favorite tools, save that file, and load your preprocessed NRRD file with an `NrrdLoader`:

```
"partitions": {
  "hemi": {
    "type": "nrrd",
    "source": "my_file.nrrd"
  }
}
```